# Browsync with gulp doesn´t refresch browser

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

**SOLVED**

If you get messenge in command line `(Reloading browsers...)` and it didn´t reload browser you must add html & body tag to your index.php / index.hmtl file.

Comment: No code? #magicshow

Comment: Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Can you give full of gulpfile.js?

Comment: Yes, I update and add full gulpfile.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, why you need two tasks, if one task can do it?

```
gulp.task('style', function () {
    return gulp.src( styleSRC )
    /*********** COMPILE ***********/
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'compact'
        // outputStyle: 'compressed'
        // outputStyle: 'nested'
        // outputStyle: 'expanded'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe( sourcemaps.init( { loadMaps: true } ) )
    .pipe( autoprefixer( AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS ) )
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest( styleDEST )) // Sass -> css
    /*********** MINIFY ***********/
    .pipe(cleanCSS({
        level: '2',
        debug: true}, function(details) {
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.originalSize + ' kb');
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.minifiedSize + ' kb');
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.timeSpent + ' ms');
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.efficiency + '%');
        }))
    .pipe( rename( { suffix: '.min' } ) ) // rename to .min
    .pipe(gulp.dest( styleDEST )) // Publish
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    .pipe( notify( { message: 'TASK: "style" Completed! ', onLast: true } ) );
});
```

Now, back to your problem. Browsersync only cares about your CSS when it's finished compiling - make sure you call `.stream()` after `gulp.dest`.

```
.pipe(browserSync.stream())
```

You only use `browserSync.stream()` in the minify task, but not for style task. Also, make sure `<body>` tag must be present.

> Browsersync works by injecting an asynchronous script tag (`<script async>...</script>`) right after the  tag during initial request. **In order for this to work properly the `<body>` tag must be present**. Alternatively you can provide a custom rule for the snippet using [snippetOptions](https://browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-snippetOptions)

Comment: Thanks for help! My problem was: I don´t have any html and body tags in my index file. I has only h1 & h2 :) Thank you!